# Openpyxl, append key value to column if key matched with cell?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an excel file containing:

A1 = Company Name
B1 = Mobile

etc

I generated a dictionary out of some data having the colmumn headers as keys, comparing the cells to keys to check if it matches. On match, I want to compare the cells of that column against the value of matched key. If value is not present `append` to the column.

```
for key in dictionary_test.keys():
    os.chdir("C:\Python34")
    wb = load_workbook("Trying web.xlsx")
    ws = wb.active
    for row in ws.iter_rows():
        for cell in row:
            if key == cell.value:

        ws.append(dictionary_test)
        wb.save("Trying web.xlsx")
```

I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "", line 8, in 
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 692, in append
>      col_idx = column_index_from_string(col_idx)
>    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils__init__.py", line 112, in >column_index_from_string
>      raise ValueError("{0} is not a valid column name".format(str_col))
>   ValueError: Contact Person is not a valid column name

How would I go about correcting this?

Structure of the excel file:

A1 = Company

B1 = Mobile

C1 = Phone

D1 = Contact Person

E1 = Call Us

F1 = Address

Currently there is nothing in the cells below them.

Comment: Without knowing what is in the XLSX file i am afraid noone can help. Please include at least the structure of that file (column headers + a sample line will suffice) as the error message is something about the structure of that file.

Comment: @Dunkelstern just added details. Currently the file just has values in A1, B1. I simply want to compare the key to A1 and if matched, compare value under A1 to key value, and append the value to an empty cell under the same column.

Comment: Where does the String `Contact Person` in the error message come from, is it somewhere in the XLSX or did you skip some code in your example?

Comment: @Dunkelstern, sorry I was being a bit lazy there. Added everything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing multiple lists and their items to excel cell values, if not present write the list items into new rows, correct approach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41850671/comparing-multiple-lists-and-their-items-to-excel-cell-values-if-not-present-wr)

Answer (score 1):

I assume in `dictionary_test` you try something like this:

```python
dictionary_test = {
    "Company": "Microsoft",
    "Mobile": "1234567",
    ...
}
```

The library does not know that the first line in your excel sheet should be the column names. So you try to unpack that in the loop but you're passing it the complete dictionary in the append line. Try an array instead. Like so:

```python
data = [ "Microsoft", "1234567", ... ]
ws.append(data)
```

How does the input data get generated? Is it from somewhere out of your reach or could you just pre-sort that into arrays to append it?